# Find the smallest subspace of $\Bbb{R}^2$ which contains 2 elements

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Cheers, after the last question of mine regarding the smallest subspace of a vector space I am here for a follow up!

**I would gladly appreciate if everyone could provide a solution or at least a comment to guide me, instead of downvoting everything.**

Let the vector space $\Bbb{R}^2$ have two elements, $(11,13)$ and $(20,22)$. How can I find the smallest subspace, which contains both of these elements? From the last question, I now know that if A is the smallest subspace of $\Bbb{R}^2$ containing (11,13), then $A = \{ t(11,13): t \in \Bbb{R} \}$ and if B is the smallest subspace of $\Bbb{R}^2$ containing $(20,22)$, then $B = \{ λ(20,22): λ \in \Bbb{R} \}$. As noted, since the subspace has to have multiples of these points as elements, I can come up with the previous sets, which also hold for addition and the zero-vector (scalar multiplication trivially holds). What about two points though? Is there a way to find the span of this set and come up with the answer? Also if I wanted the intersection of A and B, would I be able to find this set, if I regarded these sets as lines that go through the origin? e.g. the line $11y-13x=0$ seems to produce the same vector space as A. Is this possible or should I correct my thinking?

Comment: If two elements of $\mathit{R}^2$ are LD then smallest subspace is the line passing through them and the origin. If they are LI then smallest subspace is $\mathit{R}^2$ itself.

Comment: You appear to interchangeably use the words subset and subspace in the body of the question - it is important to note that they are not the same! The smallest subset containing two vectors is simply the set containing them. The subspace is probably what you're asking about.

Comment: @preferred_anon Thanks for noticing! Fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V$ is a vector space (as $\mathbb{R}^2$ is), and $u$ and $v$ are two elements of $V$, then the smallest subspace of $V$ containing both vectors is called the [*span* of the vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span). There are three distinct cases for $u$ and $v$, giving rise to different dimensions for the span.

1. $u$ and $v$ are [linearly independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence). In other words, the only pair of scalars $\alpha, \beta$ such that $\alpha u + \beta v = 0$ is $\alpha=\beta=0$. In this case, $\text{span}(u, v)$ has dimension 2, and in your example therefore has to equal $\mathbb{R}^2$.
2. $u$ and $v$ are not linearly independent, but also not both zero. Then without loss of generality, $u \ne 0$ and $v=\lambda u$ for some scalar $\lambda$ (possibly $\lambda=0$). This implies that $\text{span}(u, v) = \text{span}(u) = \{tu, t \in \mathbb{R}\}$, which has dimension 1. Note that if one of the vectors is zero, then it is impossible for them to be linearly independent.
3. $u = v = 0$. Then $\text{span}(u, v) = \{0\}$, which has dimension 0.

To find the intersection of the two subspaces $\text{span}(u)$ and $\text{span}(v)$, note that if $w \in \text{span}(u)$ then $w = \alpha u$ for some $\alpha$ (possibly 0). Similarly $w = \beta v$. There are two cases:

- $w = 0$: $0$ is in the intersection of *any* two subspaces.
- $w \ne 0$: Therefore, $\alpha, \beta \ne 0$ and $u, v \ne 0$, but $\alpha u - \beta v = 0$. Therefore $u, v$ are linearly dependent and not both zero - the spans are equal lines. Conversely, if $u,v$ are linearly dependent then you easily get a non-zero element of the intersection.

Finally, to answer the specific statement you made: the line defined by the equation $11y-13x=0$ and $\{t(11,13)\}$ are the same line. This is because:

- If $v = (x,y) = t(11, 13)$, then $11y-13x = 11*13t - 13*11t = 0$, and
- If $11y-13x=0$, then $y = \tfrac{13}{11}x$, so $(x, y) = (x,
     \tfrac{13}{11}x) = \tfrac{1}{11}x(11, 13) = t(11, 13)$.